# Beyond Schwinger field strength

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, non-linear-systems, pair-production

1. What happens to a field theory when it  surpasses the [Schwinger limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit)?
2. Can we use the same theory or should we modify it?
3. That is, how is a field theory defined in the "supercritical" regime with respect to Lorentz/Poincaré or gauge/diffeomorphism symmetries?